# Redirecting to other page in jquery mobile after ajax call

Tags: cordova

I have made one ajax call for authenticating userinfo.after its successfull call it will redirect to other file home.html. but its not working for me.

I have tried:

> window.location.href="url";

and also:

> $.mobile.channgepage('url');

plz help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.open("home.html", '_self');
```

Secondly there is an syntax error in your code

Change this

```
$.mobile.channgepage('url');
```

To

```
$.mobile.changePage("home.html")
```

You also need to add Jquery and JQM reference

[Link](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)